# Codenameone sending iOS App Store build with Enterprise distribution certificate fails with error

Tags: ios, build, codenameone

I'm using Codenameone to build iOS app for Enterprise(In House) distribution. When I choose **"Send IOS app store build"** command, I get Build Error from Codenameone server:

> None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements

The full log is [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/731912fc-d6c6-4384-9d6d-329651a6aced-1482952397123-error.txt).

I've defined both debug and production certificates and created .p12 files and provisioning profiles for them.
I can't figure out what cause this problem, because when I choose **"Send IOS debug build"** everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found solution in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/d0Lua4JjrtU).

If you are distributing your iOS app with Enterprise certificate, you need to use this parameter in your build hints:

> ios.distributionMethod=enterprise

After I add this the build was successful.
More about build hints: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html

Comment: Well done. FYI in the new version of the Codename One Settings (next plugin update) we have checkboxes in the ios signing section to annotate the mode.